# Material Time picker issue in Angular

Tags: angular, timepicker

Is there any way to disable candidosales/material-time-picker input field in Angular app. While entering time with keyboard breaks everything.

Comment: When you say Keyobard, you mean regular or Mobile? And breaks everything is not computing the input time or showing some error? This is the demo stackblitz on github: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-time-picker and If I try using the keyboard to input time, it doesn't work as you pointed

Comment: Not mobile keyboard.

Comment: Please check this link https://github.com/candidosales/material-time-picker/issues/1 it is the similar issue which i'm facing.

Comment: My answer bellow may help you, have you tried?

Comment: There is Multiple timepickers on screen and also it is not working on ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: Is showing any error? Could you select the exact timerpicker?

Comment: This is my html code:

<material-timepicker color="primary" [label]="null" appearance="standard"
 (change)="onChangeHour($event, -1)"  [userTime]="exportTime"></material-timepicker>

In component.ts:

exportTime = { hour: 0, minute: 0, meriden: 'AM', format: 12 };

Comment: It isn't showing any errors. But the time pickers value is showing empty.

Comment: the repository author made an update to this time-picker with the disable and readonly attributes. check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent keyboard input, you  have to use the `onKeyDown` attribute of the input field. There you just have to write `return false`. So every time the user tries to type something, it gets cancelled. The user then can only pick a date via the Material-Date-Picker. Below i have an example for such a form field like I use them.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" color="primary">
  <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    [min]="minDate"
    [matDatepicker]="picker"
    autocomplete="off"
    onKeyDown="return false"
    placeholder="Date"
    formControlName="date"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="date.invalid"
    >Please select a date</mat-error
  >
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the documentation and currently, there isn't a "way" to access the input properties, disabled or readyonly(the most suitable) for your case.

But you can "hack" with pure javascript. Problably there's better ways around, but you have to pay attention if your time-picker is the only one in the page, see below:

**1 - FIRST CASE: Multiple timepickers on screen:
on your ngAfterViewInit() method (cause it wait for the html and controls to load)**

```
/*This will take every timepicker inputs on page. They all share this #time_Control id
index init with 0, if the timepicker you want is the first. Adjust the index accordingly
*/

ngAfterViewInit(){
    const timepickers: any[] = document.querySelectorAll('#time_Control');
    const index = 0;
    const mytimepicker = timepickers[ index ];
    mytimepicker.disabled = true;
    //or, my personal recomendation => mytimepicker.readonly = true;
}
```

**2 - SECOND CASE: One timepicker on screen:
on your ngAfterViewInit() method (cause it wait for the html and controls to load)**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    const mytimepicker: any = document.querySelector('#time_Control');
    mytimepicker.readonly = true;
}
```